# How to deploy .jar files in Plesk Obsidian 18.52.0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar, plesk-onyx

Up to and including version 17.5 Plesk Onyx came with a Tomcat installation, which is no longer supported from the current version Thus no .war files can be deployed and executed anymore.

A downgrade recommended by Plesk is not expedient in my eyes, because of the near end of life and security concerns. How can I run Java code on a Plesk-managed server?